# Disable JIT Optimizations for specific .NET Core Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

For Full Framework assemblies one can disable the JIT by adding a ini file with the same name  as the assembly (e.g. Foo.dll and Foo.dll.ini) with the following content:

```
[.NET Framework Debugging Control]
AllowOptimize=0
```

In .NET Core I can disable JITing of everything by setting the `COMPlus_JITMinOpts` environment variable to 1 for the process. Is there a way to disable the JIT compiler only for specific assemblies? Disabling optimizations for the whole process leads to large slowdowns, even if I'm only interested in debugging a single assembly.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the DLL in the DEBUG output folder?

Comment: @Matthew Because I want to debug into NuGets. Now certainly I could get the source code of the exact version I'm using, build the nuget myself in debug mode and update the code to use that debug nuget instead, but that's a giant hassle.

Comment: So you are debugging into the NuGet code?

Comment: Does this help? https://endjin.com/blog/2022/05/debugging-nuget-packages-understanding-debugging-symbols-and-using-source-link

Comment: The JIT compiler will always be used, there is no interpreter as in Java. You are asking about disabling *optimizations*.

Comment: It's not really just optimisations you need to disable - you will need the symbols too (as per the link I posted above).

Comment: @Matthew Sure I have to use source link (or a symbol server, or include pdbs and source in the package - there's been a lot of variants on how to debug into NuGets over the years), but that has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: So let's just assume I know how to debug into NuGets, because I've been doing that for a good decade. And as the post shows I already know how to do it selectively for NetFx  assemblies and how to do it for a whole .NET Core process. The only interesting part is how to tell the JIT compiler to not optimize a single assembly instead of the whole process.

Comment: There appears to be no such setting, at least none that's documented. Consider opening an issue in the [runtime repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/).

Comment: It takes [an attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjitoptimizerdisabled?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-debuggableattribute-isjitoptimizerdisabled).  Must be embedded in the assembly itself, so you have to rebuild from the source.  The question is too vague to give a direct link.

Comment: @Hans Well clearly I don't *have to* rebuild from source, since I can override the attribute perfectly fine in both NetFx and .NET Core during startup. The only limitation seems to be that I can't override it *per assembly* in .NET Core, contrary to NetFx.